# I need help trying to write a javascript regular expression

Tags: regex

I need help trying to write a JavaScript regular expression to select `Harry` and `Anderson` from this text:

```
H6 Harry - Anderson
```

So I want the word after the hyphen and word before the hyphen.

Comment: You'll need to give us a little more context first.  For example, can you give us samples of the rest of the text.  Do you want regex to only pick out words with capital letters?  Words that are on either side of a hyphen? Words that are after a (letter)(number) combination?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the "The"s in the results, or that you want to go from "H6 Harry - Anderson" to ["Harry"],["Anderson"]?

Comment: Please post a few more examples, and enclose all strings in quotes. Include examples of different types of input.

Comment: I tweaked the formatting so it makes more sense.  @WingMan, is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if there's always a hyphen present, you can use:

```
/(\w+) - (\w+)/
```

*(PCRE syntax)*

In JavaScript you can use the object method to catch the text in question:

```
string.match(/(\w+) - (\w+)/);
```

You can use the `/g` modifier to scan the whole chunk of text, it keeps backreferences in `$1` up to `$99`.